# Convert sql to doctrine orm in aend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a query which looks like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb.users
left join mydb.job on
users.id = job.userid;
```

Now I am using doctrine orm in querying database but I am newbie here. 
What I have done so far is below but it doesn't work as expected.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select(array('a', 'c'))
        ->from('Admin\Entity\User', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.id', 'c');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();

return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the from clause and array from clause select

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('u');

$qb->select('u', 'j')
   ->leftJoin('u.jobs', 'j')

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();

return $results;
```

it is mandatory that your users entity contains a "one to many" jobs for the attribute.

trick to display the SQL output :

```
var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());
```